# How to use shell functions in a script

Tags: zsh

I have a shell function that I am trying to call from my zsh script but it is not finding the function. I assume this is because the script has no context to the environment? How do I get the script to utilize the shell functions?

```
$ function foo { echo bar }
$ foo
bar
```

In my `my_script.zsh` file I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

echo Foo
foo
```

But when I run this I get:

```
$ ./my_script.zsh
Foo
./my_script.zsh:4: command not found: foo
```

Is there any way I can use my shell functions inside of my scirpt?

Comment: A script should typically source the file containing the function it needs explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the function. While bash would have so-called *exported functions*, with which you could achieve the desired effect (though I don't consider it wise to do so), zsh doesn't. A common approach is to put the function definitions in a separated file (say, `funlib.zsh`), and source this file from every zsh process which needs them, i.e. something like

```
source ~/lib/funlib.zsh
```

(or wherever you put your function definitions).